# Make cells in a grid non-editable

Tags: c#, winforms, syncfusion

In my syncfusion grid, I have to make some series cells non-editable based on the type.
If the type is an 'XXX' then the cell is editable, 
If the type is a 'YYY','ZZZ' then cell is non-editable

So here;'s what I did.

```
 private void theGrid_CurrentCellChanging(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        fp_data_typ typ;
        int nSeries = theData.GetNumSeries();
        for (int i = 0; i < nSeries; i++)
        {
            typ = theData.CheckType(i);
            if (!(typ == 'XXX'))
            {

                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }

    }
```

I am not sure if I should be using theGrid_CurrentCellChanging event or theGrid_CurrentCellStartEditing. Documentation is not very clear. Gives me a ton of events to handle cell edit.

The code earlier works in an incorrect way. It does not work if the grid has a combination of editable and non-editable series. i:e if it has both xxx)editable and 'yyy'(non-editable), it makes both non-editable.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the column index of the current cell and from there set e.cancel to true/false. Instead of setting e.cancel for the whole grid once, I went for the cell being edited.

Answer (score 0):

Below events will help you to achieve your requirement.

```
//Use this if you want to control the ReadOnly setting while loading itself
grid.QueryCellInfo += new GridQueryCellInfoEventHandler(grid_QueryCellInfo);

void grid_QueryCellInfo(object sender, GridQueryCellInfoEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Style.CellValue.Equals("YYY"))
    {
        e.Style.ReadOnly = true;
    }
}

//Use this if you want to Validate while Editing
grid.CurrentCellValidating += new CurrentCellValidatingEventHandler(grid_CurrentCellValidating);

void grid_CurrentCellValidating(object sender, CurrentCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    //Will deactive the cell and new value will be discarded
    //e.NewValue = e.OldValue;

    //To remain in Edit mode without committing the vlaue
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Thanks,
Sivakumar